# How create asimetric cone in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, surface

I need to create a surface generate by rotation on y axis of shape formed by two curves. I already have the equation for this two curves. [Here is the shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4bp7.png)

I already create the surface but for simetric cone formed by one of this curve, here is my script:

```
h=20;
rw=1;
hw=5;
L=25;
r=linspace(rw,L,50);
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,25);
[r,theta] = meshgrid(r,theta);
xx=r.*cos(theta);
yy=r.*sin(theta);
z=sqrt(log(r/rw)*(h^2-hw^2)/log(L/rw)+hw^2); %Fuction of curve
surf(xx,yy,z)
```

[Here is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRRmK.jpg)

In the other curve is the same fuction (z) but change r,h,L

Thanks for your help,

Comment: what are the equations for the two curves?

Comment: z1(r1)=sqrt(log(r1/rw)*(h1^2-hw^2)/log(L1/rw)+hw^2) and z2(r2)=sqrt(log(r2/rw)*(h2^2-hw^2)/log(L2/rw)+hw^2), only change some constants in the second equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use *parameter grids* instead of scalars:

```
% parameters
h=[20 25];
rw=1;
hw=5;
L=[25 30];
nr = 50;
nt = 25;
theta=linspace(0,2*pi,nt);
rmax = linspace(L(1),L(2),floor((nt+1)/2));
% generating **grids** for all parameters
l = [linspace(L(1),L(2),floor((nt+1)/2)) linspace(L(2),L(1),floor((nt)/2))];
hh = [linspace(h(1),h(2),floor((nt+1)/2)) linspace(h(2),h(1),floor((nt)/2))];
[~,thetaGrid] = meshgrid(1:nr,theta);
[~,lGrid] = meshgrid(1:nr,l);
[~,hGrid] = meshgrid(1:nr,hh);
rGrid = zeros(size(thetaGrid));
for ii = 1:floor((nt+1)/2)
    rGrid(ii,:) = linspace(rw,rmax(ii),nr);
end
rGrid(ceil((nt+1)/2):end,:) = rGrid(floor((nt+1)/2):-1:1,:);
% set coordinate grids
xx=rGrid.*cos(thetaGrid);
yy=rGrid.*sin(thetaGrid);
z=sqrt(log(rGrid./rw).*(hGrid.^2-hw^2)./log(lGrid./rw)+hw.^2); %Fuction of curve
% plot
surf(xx,yy,z)
```

[image: asymmetric cone]